# Issue with changing UIImageView Position

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am tring to move an UIImageView on an ios device. I am able to moving it but there is a problem with the offset, because when i click on the image I set the ImageView center as anchor movement point.
How can I set the touched screen CGPOint as anchor point to move the UIImageView ?

```
override func touchesBegan( . . . ){
   location = touch.location(in : self.view)
   . . . 
   imageView.center = location
   . . .
}

override func touchesMoved( . . . ){
   location = touch.location(in : self.view)
   . . . 
   imageView.center = location
   . . .
}
```

Comment: You'd have to do a hit test during touchesBegan on the UIImageView to check which point the touch is on the UIImageView and remember that offset. Then during touchesMoved, change your imageView.center to that of the touch plus the offset first registered.

Comment: I tried to do this, but  can't get out with a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var offset: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero

override func touchesBegan( . . . ){
    offset = touch.location(in: imageView)
    offset.x = (imageView.bounds.width / 2) - offset.x
    offset.y = (imageView.bounds.height / 2) - offset.y

    location = touch.location(in : self.view)
    location.x = location.x + offset.x
    location.y = location.y + offset.y
    . . .
    imageView.center = location
    . . .
}

override func touchesMoved( . . . ){
    location = touch.location(in : self.view)
    location.x = location.x + offset.x
    location.y = location.y + offset.y
    . . .
    imageView.center = location
    . . .
}
```